# I want to make a daily random facts app pertaining to all things Marvel. It'll be a ton of facts, so what is the best way to store all of the data?

Tags: ios, swift

It's going to show a new fact that happened on whatever the current day is, so pretty much like the "On This Day" feature that Facebook has, but for Marvel (and later on I want to do Disney and such too). This means I'll probably need 365 facts from all days of the year, and I'm not sure if storing them in a simple array would be all I need.

Comment: I would store it as a JSON file and read it, or use something like Firebase Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase to store and fetch the data. Locally storing so much data is not a good practice. Or if you have some backend skills or backend developer in your team ask him to make an API for it.